# How do I pass the value of a variable to an specific page element with solely JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have:

```
var url="http://www.google.html";
```

how do I put the URL variable value as the `href` value of a specific anchor tag in the page?
I know about `str.link()` but how can I use that with a specific element? And can I use link*( to build anchors of images? That didn't seem to work for me. Thanks for the help

Comment: Note that the `link` method is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anchor elements:

```
<a id="myAnchor">link me!</a>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
var url = "http://www.google.html";  // .html is the new .com
var myAnchor = document.getElementById('myAnchor');
myAnchor.href = url;
</script>
```